# Socket.io with PhoneGap disconnects when application is in the background

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, socket.io

I have a phonegap app (currently on Adroid only) that uses socket.io against a node.js server.
Everything works fine when the application is in foreground. 
The problem is that when it goes to background, after 3-4 minutes I see a disconnect on the server. This happens even if from the client I send emit() while the app is in background.

I have tried all socket.io options, e.g. keepalive, timeout, etc., but nothing helped so far.

Anyone with similar problem and possible solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess that this is a battery management issue and by default apps are prevented from keeping sockets alive and regularly transmitting (which is what a socket.io socket does) when in the background.

Comment: After a long research and testing, it appears that this is not possible. Even from a background service, socket.io is disconnected after some time. There are restrictions from the OS. The only solution is to write a native Android process and to set various permission. As this is not something I want to do, I finally decided to go with GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) and it seems that it works very well.